# configuring squid to use a different proxy server as its internet connection

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm setting up a squid proxy on my computer (I use ubuntu).

However, my computer is not connected to the internet directly. I connect to the internet via an authenticating proxy (incidentally, also squid). I want to set up my own squid to send all requests to the internet via the other proxy.

I was mucking around with the tutorials and documentation, and found something called `cache_peer`. I tried using it, but to no avail.

You may ask, "Why are you doing this?"

A: My final goal is:

If my squid recieves a request to `http://fictitiouswebsite.com/page/article`, then it will convert the request into `http://ficticiouswebsite.com/page/artice?google`.

This is just like a simple URL rewrite (I know this term from apache).

So if you know how to do that, please tell me that too.

Thanks,

jrh

PS: i've never configured a squid proxy before in my life. this is my first time.

Comment: What version of Squid are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [Squid documentation for the cache_peer directive](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_peer/). For a proxy on parentcache.foo.com:8080, you could use something like:

```
cache_peer parentcache.foo.com parent 8080 0 no-query default login=user:password
acl all src 0.0.0.0/0 
never_direct allow all
```

Comment: Yep, that will push all traffic through a proxy with a user and password.